# How to use PHPDoc?

Tags: php, phpdoc

My ide always asks me to prescribe all @param and @thorws but sometimes there are a lot of these parameters, it turns out something like (sometimes more)

```
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Conference $conference
     * @param CommentRepository $commentRepository
     * @param string $photoDir
     * @param Environment $twig
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     * @param MessageBusInterface $bus
     * @param Comment $comment
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @return Response
     * @throws LoaderError
     * @throws RuntimeError
     * @throws SyntaxError
     */
```

There are a lot of them and I think they pollute the code because the types I specify in function parameters.

```
public function show(Request $request,
                         Conference $conference,
                         CommentRepository $commentRepository,
                         string $photoDir, Environment $twig,
                         EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
                         MessageBusInterface $bus, Comment $comment,
                         Registry $registry)
```

Sometimes this documentation becomes much larger than a function.

I also looked at demo symfony and found no enumeration of parameters there.
https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/master/src/Controller/BlogController.php

**Do you think we should write all these params and throws in the method documentation?**

Comment: Sometimes having a lot of parameters in a class method may indicate that there is something wrong with the design.  Do some of these parameters ONLY get used in this method or should they be store as part of the class.

Comment: @NigelRen this is just an example, it seems to me even 4 parameters and 3 throws greatly interfere with reading the code

Comment: May be worth having a look at something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805084/is-phpdoc-verbosity-more-trouble-than-its-worth